# When I do an imshow with fig.canvas.draw, why are the margins so large?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, canvas, visualization

I am trying to perform a imshow then run a conversion from matplotlib.figure to a numpy.array. However, I am getting large margins on the top/bottom.

When I don't convert to numpy array, I am happy with the results:

```
# draw axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 120)
ax.set_ylim(-7, 7)

# add image
img = plt.imread('https://www.clker.com/cliparts/7/x/9/Q/Q/p/brown-car-top-view.svg.hi.png')
x, y = 10, 0
ax.imshow(img, extent=[x - 2.5, x + 2.5, y - 2, y + 2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, when I try to convert to numpy.array, I get large margins.

```
# draw axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 120)
ax.set_ylim(-7, 7)

# add image
img = plt.imread('https://www.clker.com/cliparts/7/x/9/Q/Q/p/brown-car-top-view.svg.hi.png')
x, y = 10, 0
ax.imshow(img, extent=[x - 2.5, x + 2.5, y - 2, y + 2])

# convert matplotlib.figure to numpy.array
plt.close()
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
fig.canvas.draw()
image = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')
image = image.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

# show numpy array
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image: bad]

However, if I comment out the imshow, I don't get margins (although the aspect ratio is messed up)

```
# draw axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 120) 
ax.set_ylim(-7, 7)

# add image
img = plt.imread('https://www.clker.com/cliparts/7/x/9/Q/Q/p/brown-car-top-view.svg.hi.png')
x, y = 10, 0
# ax.imshow(img, extent=[x - 2.5, x + 2.5, y - 2, y + 2]) # comment this out

# convert matplotlib.figure to numpy.array
plt.close()
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
fig.canvas.draw()
image = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')
image = image.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

# show numpy array
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your default figure size (`matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize']` which is typically `[6.4, 4.8]`). So you need to adopt your figure size *before* setting the tight layout, e.g.

```
fig.set_size_inches(3.8, 0.7)
```

Result:
[image]

The above example is for 100 dpi. In order to get the array in the required pixel size you may also want to set `fig.set_dpi` as needed.